# How to add a PieChart subplot in a JFree BarChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart, pie-chart, bar-chart, subplot

I want to include a PieChart subplot over a JFree BarChart. The idea is represent how many items are included in the chart vs the total number of items to see how long is the Long Tail.

Here you can a sample image. How can I build something similar with JFreeChart?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `BufferedImage` from any chart using [`createBufferedImage()`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/JFreeChart.html#createBufferedImage%28int,%20int%29) and add it to a chart as an [`XYImageAnnotation`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/annotations/XYImageAnnotation.html).

Comment: Do you have any small example?

Comment: I've done both individually, but not combined them. You might start with the two [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/demo/package-summary.html), [`BarChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.html#line.62) and [`PieChartDemo1`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/src-html/org/jfree/chart/demo/PieChartDemo1.html#line.56). Conveniently, the API links to the source.